Did the prophecies in the Bible employ Vaticinium ex eventu?
Vaticinium ex eventu, or prophecy after the event, is a Latin expression that designates an apparently premonitory prophecy, but in reality is retrospectively elaborated, after the event it supposedly predicts. It is a rhetorical and historical artifice where a text is constructed as if it were an anticipated prediction, when in fact it was written after the events, creating the illusion of a prophetic ability or prior knowledge. This technique is often used in religious, historical, and literary texts, where authors seek to confer authority and credibility to a narrative, making it appear that certain prophecies or predictions were truly anticipated, when in essence they are just disguised descriptions of events that have already occurred.
Some scholars argue that several prophecies in the Bible (Enoch, Daniel, Apocalypse) actually employ the Vaticinium ex eventu technique. Are there studies that oppose this claim?
my source: https://youtu.be/5PN_6bOZBTs?si=6cpKuMO7R-6EWoJn&t=1041 (use english subtitles).
Here is a textual summary of the arguments presented in the video:
The Retrospective Nature of Biblical Prophecies: Analyzing the Book of Enoch and Other Examples
The Book of Enoch, specifically the First Enoch or Enoch Ethiopic, is a prime example of how "prophecies" in ancient literature often reflect historical events that had already occurred. This phenomenon is analyzed through the historical and textual evidence found in Enoch and corroborated by examples in the Bible. The reasoning is as follows:
1. Historical Context Reflecting Past Events
The Book of Enoch describes visions of future events, particularly those involving the Hellenistic Greek domination over Judea and the subsequent Maccabean revolt (2nd century BCE). These events are presented as predictions made by Enoch, a patriarch mentioned in Genesis (5:24), who supposedly lived before the Flood.
However, from a historical perspective, the content aligns so closely with these known events that it suggests the book was written after they occurred. This technique is known academically as vaticinium ex eventu (prophecy after the event).
Example:

In the Book of Dreams section (part of First Enoch), allegories describe events in which symbolic animals (e.g., bulls, sheep, and goats) represent nations and figures like Judas Maccabeus appear as prophesied liberators. These specific historical references make it clear that the author was writing retrospectively.

2. Comparison to Other Biblical Texts
Similar patterns of retrospective prophecy are found in other biblical works:

The Book of Daniel (Chapters 7–12) includes "visions" of four beasts representing successive empires:

Babylon
Persia
Greece
The Seleucid kingdom (Antiochus IV Epiphanes).

These beasts are presented as future entities seen by Daniel during the Babylonian exile (6th century BCE). However, scholars argue that the text was written during the Maccabean period (2nd century BCE) because the historical details align precisely up to that era but fail to predict events beyond it.

Epistle of Jude (New Testament):

Jude 1:14-15 quotes a passage from the Book of Enoch, further emphasizing the influence of Enochian traditions on biblical prophecy.



This pattern shows that prophets often wrote in contexts of political oppression and presented historical struggles as "divine predictions" to inspire hope for divine intervention.
3. Textual and Literary Indicators

Lack of Early References:
No Jewish or Christian texts before the 2nd century BCE reference Enoch's prophecies, implying they were not widely known until that period.

Style and Language:
The vocabulary, grammar, and themes in Enoch align better with post-Persian Jewish texts, suggesting a late composition.


4. Motivation for Retrospective Prophecy
Authors in these historical periods used "prophecy" as a tool to:

Provide hope to oppressed communities (e.g., under Greek or Roman rule).
Legitimize current struggles as part of a divine plan.
Reinforce religious faith by portraying historical events as foreseen by revered figures.

This approach reassures readers that divine justice will eventually prevail, aligning their suffering with a greater cosmic purpose.

Conclusion
The Book of Enoch, along with works like Daniel and other apocalyptic literature, demonstrates that prophecies often reflect past events disguised as predictions. The precise alignment of prophetic texts with historical realities that predate their composition highlights their retrospective nature. This pattern, coupled with literary and historical analysis, indicates that these prophecies were constructed to address contemporary crises and inspire hope for divine deliverance.

Key Biblical References

Genesis 5:24 - Enoch's unique relationship with God:
"Enoch walked with God; then he was no more because God took him."

Jude 1:14-15 - Direct quotation from the Book of Enoch:
"Enoch, the seventh from Adam, prophesied about them: 'See, the Lord is coming with thousands upon thousands of his holy ones to judge everyone...' "

Daniel 7–12 - Retrospective "visions" of successive empires, particularly up to Antiochus IV Epiphanes.



This reasoning reveals how prophecy, though presented as foresight, often serves as a retrospective interpretation to inspire hope and faith in periods of turmoil.

You will need to be more specific.  Daniel 2 is regarded as a prophecy from Daniel's time to the end of the world and has thus far proven accurate.

"Some scholars argue that …" is far too vague. Explicit quotations and sources are needed. As it is currently asked, a corresponding answer would be something like "Yes, there are some studies that oppose this claim", with no mention of what those studies are. ¶But even with appropriate citations, this question would be much better suited for the Christianity.SE site.

I think this is an extremely important question but unfortunately it will generate strongly held opinions and will thus be closed as opinion-based. I suggest examining specific prophecies. I think the moderators will allow questions such as "what are the arguments for [cite specific prophecy] being a case of Vaticinium ex eventu?" If I recall correctly we've been advised not to ask for "pro" and "con" arguments in the same question, although I'm not sure why.

@RayButterworth, here is my source: https://youtu.be/5PN_6bOZBTs?si=6cpKuMO7R-6EWoJn&t=1041 (use english subtitlrs)

@Dottard, he point is that whoever wrote the text did so based on events that had already happened, projecting them into the future. Watch this video (use English subtitles): https://youtu.be/5PN_6bOZBTs?si=6cpKuMO7R-6EWoJn&t=1041

@HumbertoJoséBortolossi says that the source is in a YouTube video. Does it make sense for everyone that reads this question to have to watch that video? It would be far better if the question itself contained explicit quotations of the relevant details.

@RayButterworth, I understand your point, but I believe the use of a video as a source remains highly relevant in this context. Videos uniquely combine visuals, audio, content, and often music, creating a powerful medium for storytelling and knowledge transfer.
Moreover, the presenter in this video is a scholar with deep expertise on biblical subjects, which adds credibility to the content presented. As Marshall McLuhan famously stated, "The medium is the message"—highlighting that the form in which information is delivered is integral to its impact and understanding.

@HumbertoJoséBortolossi, I don't disagree with what you said. But the result is that I'm not going to spend time slowly reading subtitles on a long video. So, even if I did know the answer, it's not going to happen. If the Question contained explicit quotations of the "several prophecies" (or even one) and a brief summary of what their arguments are, I would spend some time on it. I doubt I'm the only such reader here that isn't going to bother with the video. ¶ And more significantly, McLuhan also said "The medium is the massage.", and I don't want to have my behaviour manipulated.

@RayButterworth, ok! I've updated the question to include the main arguments presented in the video, including explicit quotations. is it better so?

Much, but Enoch is a poor example though. More than 2000 years ago, Judaism had rejected it: "the Book of Enoch was excluded from both the formal canon of the Tanakh [Old testament] and the Septuagint". The book is not included in most Bibles, and even though the Catholic Church does include it for historical purposes, it is not considered sacred: "By the fifth century, the Book of Enoch was mostly excluded from Christian biblical canons, and it is now regarded as scripture only by the Ethiopian Orthodox Tewahedo Church and the Eritrean Orthodox Tewahedo Church". [Wikipedia quotes]

As for Daniel, the argument "scholars argue that the text was written during the Maccabean period (2nd century BCE) because the historical details align precisely up to that era but fail to predict events beyond it." makes no sense. If I today correctly predict the winners of the next 4 Superbowls , ten years from now would it make sense to conclude that my prediction must have been written after 2028 because it doesn't predict the winners of 2029 or after?
